# SURF features for colmap reconstruction

Tags: python, surf

I'm detecting and computing surf features on a dataset in python with the function: `keypoints, descriptors = cv2.detectAndCompute(images, None)`. I then match them using a `cv2.DescriptorMatcher_BRUTEFORCE` matcher. The goal is to import these features and matches to colmap to reconstruct a 3D scene.

I extended the surf features to have 128b. The problem is that colmap expects the features to be in a certain format: https://colmap.github.io/tutorial.html . However, the surf features I extract with python have very small values for X Y SCALE and ORIENTATION. Also some scales are negative, which leads to errors in colmap. Also X and Y should be between 0 and number of pixels, but they are all really small numbers close to 0. All other values are set to 0 on purpose before importing the features to colmap.

Is there a way to convert the python surf descriptors to colmap format or is there something wrong with my descriptors?

I visualized the features in python and they seem to be fine. Below is an example file containing the surf descriptors for one of the images.

Thanks for any help!

[image: surf descriptors example]